# Accessing S3 object with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

longtime front-end dev trying to pick up some back-end stack.  I'm taking a course through Coursera on using NodeJS with AWS.  The first assignment had us set up some IAM policies/users, upload a JSON object to S3, and then attempt to load and console.log the contents of that object using the aws-sdk with selectObjectContent.

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm running (to be honest, it was 90% supplied by the course):

```
function readDragonsFromS3(bucketName, fileName)
{

    s3.selectObjectContent({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Expression: "select * from S3Object",
        ExpressionType: 'SQL',
        Key: fileName,
        InputSerialization: {
            JSON: {
                Type: 'DOCUMENT',
            }
        },
        OutputSerialization: {
            JSON: {
                RecordDelimiter: ','
            }
        }
    }, function (err, data)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        } else
        {
            handleData(data);
        }
    }
    );
}
function handleData(data)
{
    const resultStream = [];
    data.Payload.on('data', (event) =>
    {
        console.log("data event");
    })
    .on("end", () => 
    {
        console.log("end event");
    })
    .on("error", (err) =>
    {
        console.log(err);
    });
    console.log("end of handleData");
}
```

This code compiles and runs, but does not output anything to the console. I believe the expected outcome would be at least one print-out of "data event", followed by a print-out of "end event", and possibly "end of handleData" (not necessarily in that order). I've verified that the handleData function is being called, and that the data object is non-null, but after this point, there will be a 10-15 second hang and then the program terminates.

I'm doing all of this in VSCode on my local dev machine. I followed the course instructions to set up some IAM policies and roles, and used aws configure to "login" to that user on my VSCode terminal. I've confirmed that my S3 object exists and is accessible with aws s3api get-object, which worked as expected. I've also confirmed that the bucketName and fileName parameters are correct.

I'm not sure if I'm mis-understanding the way to process the data.Payload or if there is something else going on, but any suggestions are welcome!

Instructions I've been following are [here](https://aws-tc-largeobjects.s3.amazonaws.com/DEV-AWS-MO-BuildingRedux/node-exercise-1-exploring.html), and I'm stuck on Task 5, step 3, which does not return the expected JSON output.

Comment: That code sample defines two functions, but I can't see anything that 'calls' those functions?

Comment: Hmm I didn't want to overwhelm with too much code.  Outside of these two functions, there are some other helper functions to retrieve the bucket and filenames from AWS Parameter Store, a few imports, an entry point function, and a call to the entry point.  The full file contents are very similar to this [file](https://aws-tc-largeobjects.s3.amazonaws.com/DEV-AWS-MO-BuildingRedux/downloads/listDragons.js), although I had to update the require("aws-sdk") to use the new require("@aws-sdk/client-s3") and require("@aws-sdk/client-ssm") to get around some build issues.

Comment: May be worth verifying this with awscli: [aws s3api select-object-content](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/select-object-content.html). Also, the actual [listDragons.js](https://aws-tc-largeobjects.s3.amazonaws.com/DEV-AWS-MO-BuildingRedux/downloads/listDragons.js) code issues this SQL query: `"select * from S3Object[*][*] s"` which differs from yours. Not sure that's an issue by wanted to call it out.

Comment: Good idea.  I ran that command and once I figured out the parameter syntax, it did indeed return my JSON object.  The difference in SQL query was something I did during debugging and the two different versions don't seem to make any noticeable difference in the (lack of) output

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions are third party. To perform your use case in NodeJS, use the AWS SDK for JavaScript V3. The details can be found in the JavaSCript DEV Guide here:

[What's the AWS SDK for JavaScript?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

NodeJS specific content can be found here :

[Node.js considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/node-js-considerations.html)

YOu can find Amazon S3 code examples for the JS SDK here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the links.  After messing around with selectObjectContent a while longer, I gave up and tried out a version more similar to the one you linked, involving initializing a SelectObjectContentCommand and executing it with the `send` API, then writing some new code using a loop to process the result without the `data.Payload.on` structure.  This works just fine and, while I still don't understand why the original code isn't working, will function as a workaround.

Comment: Would you mind sharing that processing code with others? I have the same case; we are also using TypeScript here but can not find a good efficient way to process the result, which would be a JSON array.